# Broken magnet pieces repels each other

Tags: magnetic-fields

Why the broken magnets can't be joined together? What happens to the broken sides in terms of magnetic poles?

Answer (score 5):

Magnetic fields form closed loops.  There are no magnetic monopoles.  When you break a magnet in two, the magnetic fields of each half are closed loops just like the original unbroken magnet.  If you break a magnet in which the axial field points outward from the side of the magnet (parallel to the plane of breakage), the two halves will not rejoin, as they try to align the north pole of one with the south pole of the other.  They flip to make the alignment.

If, however, you break a magnet in which the axial field is perpendicular to the plane of breakage, the two halves will have the same polarization as the unbroken magnet, and should attract each other across the break, unless the break is jagged and ancillary magnetic fields weaken the polarization.

Comment: I have follow-up question, given that magnetic fields travel at speed $c$, would there be a minute delay in forming a closed loop? i.e just after the magnet is cut, would there exist a monople for that tiny fraction of time?

Comment: Let the magnet is  north|----|south. If broken then to repel the broken sides north |--|south and south|--|south. As per your reply I think the magnet won't repel.

Comment: @AshinVincent:  I'm not understanding your comment.  (1) If you cut a bar magnet perpendicular to the N/S axis, the two halves won't repel, as each will be polarized same as the original: One face of the break will be N while the other will be S.  (2) If you cut a neodymium disc magnet, you are cutting parallel with the N/S axis, and you wind up with two magnets sitting next to each other, each polarized the same way.  One of them will flip to bring its S pole next to the N pole of the other.

Comment: @TheGhostOfPerdition:  A magnet is a collection of similarly polarized atoms.  If you cut it in half, you reduce the strength of the larger magnet, as fewer atoms are joined together.  But there's no propagation speed.  The magnetic field of each half does not change its polarity.  The magnetic field is a closed loop before, during, and after the cut.